# Loading from Flash Drive

Tags: software-installation

I want to install Ubuntu on a computer but it currently is not able to access the internet because it operateed with Windows XP. Can I save the download to a flashdrive and download it to the computer like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install Ubuntu from USB.  There are plenty of guides on how to do so.  I find the easiest way is to mount the .ISO you downloaded to the flash drive with Universal USB Installer, available here: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Once that finishes, insert the drive and boot from  USB.  On boot there should be an install option as well as a test option to simply run Ubuntu from the USB.